# How do I repeat the program so its asks for a another word and let it only print my sentences once?

Tags: python

How do I repeat the program so its asks for a another word and let it only print my sentences once?

```
usersentence= input("Please type in a sentence without punctuation: ")
word= input("Please enter a word you want to search for in the sentence: ")
words = usersentence.split(' ')
for (i, words) in enumerate(words):
    if (words == word): 
        print("your word appears in position(s): ")
        print(i+1)

    else:
            print("Sorry yout word does not seem to be here")
```

Comment: Loop around the part where you ask for a word?

Comment: You can use a `while` loop for that. And you'll need to decide on how the program breaks out of the loop. Eg, you could  break the loop if the user enters a word of `Q` to indicate they want to quit.

Comment: you can use a while(true) around your for loop to no finish the code but to junp back.

Comment: how do i make it so the user cannot use punctuation in his sentence

Comment: Whilst this question itself is clear, it looks like it is generating a lot of additional discussion, and has also been abandoned. I wonder therefore that the question does not contain the actual question, and can be put on hold as unclear?

Answer (score 1):

To repeat the code, we use loops. You can use `for` or `while` loop depending on your problem. If you wont to repeat part of your code a specific number of times, `for` loop is your answer. For example:

```
usersentence= input("Please type in a sentence without punctuation: ")

for i in range(3):      # number of words you wont to search
    word= input("Please enter a word you want to search for in the sentence: ")
    words = usersentence.split(' ')
    passed = False      # Something to check if the word is found
    for (i, words) in enumerate(words):
        if (words == word): 
            print("your word appears in position(s): ")
            print(i+1)
            passed = True       # The word has been found

    if not passed:
        print("Sorry yout word does not seem to be here")
```

Comment: how do i make it so the user cannot use punctuation in his sentence

Comment: After where you ask for `usersentence`, add: `usersentence.translate(None, string.punctuation)`. Of course you'll need to `import string`.

Comment: how do i import srting

Comment: Huh. Just type `import string` at the beginning of the code.

Comment: Sorry but i get this :TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: Of course. You're using python 3.x. Instead of  `sersentence.translate(None, string.punctuation)` type:
`usersentence = ''.join(ch for ch in usersentence if ch not in set(string.punctuation))`

Comment: i would like it to print an error if the user uses punctuation